# visual studio 2017 vs sql management studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms, visual-studio

I just installed Visual Studio with Data Tools and removed my previously installed Management Studio, due disk constraints, and the transition has not been as easy as I expected.

Most of the time I am programming web and VS2017 is great on it. I used SSMS, though, for developing stored procedures and some *power user* work, as profiling and ad-hoc queries. The problem is that I don't know where to find the tools I was used to (profiler?!) and the organization of the environment doesn't *feel* natural for working with my utility scripts on the existing database...

So, is there a way for using VS2017 on this context or should I reinstall SSMS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although Management Studio is based-upon Visual Studio, the two are different products and have different target audiences. You will not be able to use Visual Studio to do all of the tasks that you used to use Management Studio for. Even installing the data tools and creating a SQL Server project within Visual Studio will not give you the functionality available in Management Studio.

Visual Studio is primarily used to make development easier whereas Management Studio is orientated towards making the management of SQL Server easier (with some development components.)

Like I tell a lot of the guys that work with me, choose the right tool for the job. I have both installed, though I do agree that they use a hefty amount of space when installed together.